# how to use the web speech api on mobile chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webspeech-api

The web speech API currently works in Chrome, but I have been unable to get in to work in mobile chrome on the iPhone. I haven't been able to find any info on the net, as to whether there is a way to access the API on mobile, or whether it works on Chrome for Android.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. I guess it'll eventually make it's way into mobile chrome.